# Are there any easier ways to deploy plug-in projects for myself?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I've got a few plugins that I use for my own productivity when working in Eclipse.  I've got them working by adding a feature project and an update site project.  This is with recently updated Juno.  Is this the right way to proceed?  Here's what I did:

1. new > plugin project > drstest > next > next > Hello, World Command > Next > Finish
2. drstest/build.properties > Overview > Launch an Eclipse application > (see "Sample Menu") > close application
3. new > feature project > drsfeat > next > (select drstest) > Finish
4. new > update site project > drsupd > Finish > Add Feature... > drsfeat > OK > control-s(ave) > Build All
5. help > install new software > Add... > Local... > Name: drsupd Location:C:\my\ewksp\drsupd > (select Drsfeat) > Next > Next > (accept lic) Finish > (security warning) OK > (restart) Yes
6. (after restart) > (see "Sample Menu")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

1. Create your plugin project(s)
2. File -> Export -> Deployable plugins and fragments -> Destination -> Install into host. Repository

This was added in Eclipse 3.6.